# How to make the imaginary number disappear?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, recurrence-relations

I am trying to solve one recurrence relation

> $a_n - 2a_{n-1} + 2a_{n-2} = 0, a_0 =1, a_1 = 2$

Now I was able to get the characteristic equation $r^2 -2r + 2 = 0$ , I get that $r=1 \pm i$ and everything and now I got that

$$\sqrt{2}^nA(\cos(\frac{-\pi}{4}) + i\sin(\frac{-\pi}{4}))^n + \sqrt{2}^nB(\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}) + i\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}))^n$$

which should be the same as

$$\sqrt{2}^nA(\cos(\frac{-n\pi}{4}) + i\sin(\frac{-n\pi}{4})) + \sqrt{2}^nB(\cos(\frac{n\pi}{4}) + i\sin(\frac{n\pi}{4}))$$

Now How do I go from here and make this imaginaring number $i$ disappear to get ? I feel I missing one manipulation to get the result.

$$a_n=(A\cos(n\frac\pi4)+B\sin(n\frac\pi4))\sqrt2^n.$$

Using the initial conditions $$a_0 =1 = \sqrt{2}^0A(\cos(0) + i\sin(0)) + \sqrt{2}^0B(0) + i\sin(0))$$

Which is equal to

$$a_0 =1 = A(1 + 0) + B(1 + 0)$$

and so

$$1 = A + B$$

Now using $a_1 = 2$ we  get that

$$a_1 =2 = \sqrt{2}A(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}) + \sqrt{2}B(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$$

which is $2 = 2B$ and hence $B = 1$

Now going back to $1 = A + B$ we get that $A=0$ right ?

and then we have $A=0, B=1$

Then what ?

Comment: First, you have to figure out what $A$ and $B$ must be.  You have a general form of the recurrence solution.  You need to then substitute the initial condition(s) into this general form to get the particular solution.  Once you get that, you will find that the imaginary components will cancel.

Comment: When I saw your title I thought just multiply it by zero.

Comment: You may use that $7π/4=-π/4$

Comment: @mathlover I did that but how can this help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't *make* them disappear, they should disappear on their own once you use the initial conditions $a_0=1,a_1=2$ to find $A$ and $B$. If everything is done correctly the imaginary terms will cancel at that point.

To make things easier for yourself in this specific case, you might note that $\frac{7n\pi}{4}$ is the same angle as $-\frac{n\pi}{4}$, at least as far as $\sin$ and $\cos$ is concerned.

---

Full solution:

You've figured out the characteristic equation and its solutions $1 \pm i$. That means that the general solution is of the form
$$
a_n = A(1+i)^n + B(1-i)^n\\
 = \sqrt2^nA\left(\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}4\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}4\right)\right) + \sqrt2^nB\left(\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}4\right) - i\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}4\right)\right)
$$
I prefer the top one, personally, without the $\sin$ and $\cos$. However, if you were told to find $a_{100}$ or some such, the trigonometric solution is superior in calculation complexity; since nothing is raised to any power, there are no binomial coefficients or cancelling terms to keep track of. There is also the simplification we do at the end of this answer which is possible because of the real-valued initial conditions; it is a lot simpler in the trigonometric case.

At this point we need to use the initial conditions in order to find our specific solution. We had $a_0 = 1$ and $a_1 = 2$. The first one gives us
$$
1 = a_0 = A + B
$$
while the second one gives us
$$
2 = A(1 + i) + B(1 - i) = A+B + i(A - B)
$$
Here it is tempting to say that it clearly has no solutions, since $A + B$ cannot be both $1$ and $2$ at the same time. (I was perplexed myself for a minute.) However, there is no problem if we allow $A$ and $B$ to be complex. We solve is as we would any system of two unknowns. The first equation says that $A = 1-B$, so we insert that into the second equation and get
$$
2 = 1-B + B + i(1-B-B)\\
1 = (1-2B)i\\
i = 2B-1\\
\frac12 + \frac i2 = B
$$
which gives $A = \frac12 - \frac i2$.

The solution to your problem is therefore
$$
a_n = \left(\frac12 - \frac i2\right)(1+i)^n + \left(\frac12 + \frac i2\right)(1-i)^n\\
= \sqrt2^n\left(\frac12 - \frac i2\right)\left(\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}4\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}4\right)\right) + \sqrt2^n\left(\frac12 + \frac i2 \right)\left(\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}4\right) - i\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}4\right)\right)
$$
and if we multiply out the last expression, and gather the real and imaginary parts, we get
$$
\sqrt2^n\left(\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{4}\right) + \sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{4} \right)\right)
$$
which is to say, the imaginary terms cancel out (this would've been difficult if we used $\frac{7n\pi}4$ as the angle of the second characteristic solution instead of $-\frac{n\pi}{4}$). If the initial conditions had been complex values, then $A$ and $B$ would've been such that we couldn't have cancelled the imaginary terms from this expression.

As to the comments by kmitov below: Yes, I am aware that there are ways of solving this that do not dabble into complex numbers at all, but as long as you're used to complex numbers, you don't really gain any simplicity by those methods, and you lose transparency. It also breaks completely apart should you happen to get a complex initial condition in a problem. That is why I do not follow such a solution.

Comment: He sould use only the real and imaginary part of the root $1+i$ to construct the general solution $a_n=\sqrt{2}^n(A \cos \frac{n \pi}{4}+B \sin \frac{n \pi}{4}).$ Then he can use the initial conditions to figure out A and B.

Comment: I edited my answer and I used the initial conditions and still couldn't get rid of the $i$

Comment: You do not need both roots of the equation.

Comment: how come ? @kmitov

Comment: @kmitov yes, you need both. If the original assumption when solving the equation is that the solution is of the form $r^n$, then you get the two solutions $r=1\pm i$, and the general solution is a linear combination of these two. You use the initial conditions to figure out _which_ linear combination is the correct one. What you're talking about is a shortcut which happens to work, but doesn't really help in figuring out what is really going on.

Comment: OK! Do you meen that the imaginary part has to be canceled by the initial conditions?

Comment: This is the same as for the differential equation $y''-2y'+2y=0$ $y=Ae^t\cos t + B e^t \sin t$. What initial condition do you need here?

Comment: this will be much appreciated @Arthur

Comment: And one more thing the imaginary parts have to disappear in the general solution, not because of the initial conditions.

Comment: @alkabary I have now updated my answer.

Comment: @kmitov See the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: What do I have to see?

Comment: If this is a real sequence my suggestion is correct, if you want to put complex initial condotiohs theh why du you have to remove the immaginary part?

Comment: @kmitov Yes, your suggestion seems correct, but I personally think it's a bad way to solve the problem. At least for people who are confident in basic complex arithmetic but not in recursion relations, such as the OP seems to be. Also, this is the way I would personally solve this problem in any context where complex numbers are not taboo, because to me it's easier to remember exactly how it goes.